# Set border using Python xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Is there a way to set border lines for an Excel file from Python using xlwings? I was looking at the documentation but cannot figure out.

I want to create a file like this using xlwings
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't a feature that's built into xlwings at this point. However, you can use the lower level pywin32 functions (with caveats) as described in the xlwings docs [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html).

Here's a brief example of how to set borders on a single cell using this method:

```
rng = xw.Range('A1').xl_range
for border_id in xrange(7,13):
    rng.Borders(border_id).LineStyle=1
    rng.Borders(border_id).Weight=2
```

Answer (score 0):

As annoying as this may be, you can also write (or record) a macro that creates a border and then call that macro from Python using xlwings whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
sht.range('A1:C5').api.Borders.Weight = 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are descriptive accessors to the border indices available in the `constants` module via class `BordersIndex` seen [here](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/main/xlwings/constants.py#L390).

```
class BordersIndex:
    xlDiagonalDown = 5  # from enum XlBordersIndex
    xlDiagonalUp = 6  # from enum XlBordersIndex
    xlEdgeBottom = 9  # from enum XlBordersIndex
    xlEdgeLeft = 7  # from enum XlBordersIndex
    xlEdgeRight = 10  # from enum XlBordersIndex
    xlEdgeTop = 8  # from enum XlBordersIndex
    xlInsideHorizontal = 12  # from enum XlBordersIndex
    xlInsideVertical = 11  # from enum XlBordersIndex
```

E.g.

```
import xlwings as xw
rng = xw.range('A1')
rng.Borders(xw.constants.BordersIndex.xlEdgeTop).Weight = 2
```

There are also some weight presets via `BorderWeight`.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes write code to help me remember how to do things.  This is a little def function with usage examples for setting up borders using xlwings.  Links to documentation are commented in.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

def format_borders(xl_range_obj, weight, XlBordersIndex = 'All', color = 0):

# documentation for borders object:
#   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.borders
# documentation for border object:
#   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.border(object)
# enumeration for xlbordersindex object:
#   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlbordersindex
# enumeration for xlborderweight object
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlborderweight

    try:
        border_dict = {'xlEdgeLeftAll'      : 1,    # Left edge of each cell in range, not in enumeration docs
                       'xlEdgeRightAll'     : 2,    # Right edge of each cell in range, not in enumeration docs
                       'xlEdgeTopAll'       : 3,    # Top edge of each cell in range, not in enumeration docs
                       'xlEdgeBottomAll'    : 4,    # Bottom edge of each cell in range, not in enumeration docs
                       'xlDiagonalDown'     : 5,    # Border running from the upper-left corner to the lower-right of each cell in the range.
                       'xlDiagonalUp'       : 6,    # Border running from the lower-left corner to the upper-right of each cell in the range.
                       'xlEdgeLeft'         : 7,    # Border at the left edge of the range.
                       'xlEdgeTop'          : 8,    # Border at the top of the range.
                       'xlEdgeBottom'       : 9,    # Border at the bottom of the range.
                       'xlEdgeRight'        : 10,   # Border at the right edge of the range.
                       'xlInsideVertical'   : 11,   # Vertical borders for all the cells in the range except borders on the outside of the range.
                       'xlInsideHorizontal' : 12}   # Horizontal borders for all cells in the range except borders on the outside of the range.
    
        # Custom function to "cross out" all cells in the range
        if XlBordersIndex == 'xlCrossoutAll':
            xl_range_obj.api.Borders(5).Weight = weight
            xl_range_obj.api.Borders(5).Color = color
            xl_range_obj.api.Borders(6).Weight = weight
            xl_range_obj.api.Borders(6).Color = color
            return ''

        # Custom function to format the bottom and right edges for all cells in the range
        elif XlBordersIndex == 'xlBottomRightAll': 
            xl_range_obj.api.Borders(2).Weight = weight
            xl_range_obj.api.Borders(2).Color = color
            xl_range_obj.api.Borders(4).Weight = weight
            xl_range_obj.api.Borders(4).Color = color
            return ''

        else:
            edge = border_dict.get(XlBordersIndex, 0)
            if edge:
                xl_range_obj.api.Borders(edge).Weight = weight
                xl_range_obj.api.Borders(edge).Color = color
                return ''
            else:
                xl_range_obj.api.Borders.Weight = weight
                xl_range_obj.api.Borders.Color = color
                if XlBordersIndex != 'All':
                    return f'XlBordersIndex = "{XlBordersIndex}" not found.  Formatted all edges.'
                else:
                    return ''

    except Exception as e:
        return f'Exception = {e}'

# set up dataframe for example
pd_list = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
pd_columns =  [f'Col_{__e}' for __e in pd_list]
pd_list = [[f'{__e}{__i+4}' for __e in pd_list] for __i in range(len(pd_list))]
df = pd.DataFrame(pd_list, columns = pd_columns
title = ['This is the table title']

#load Workbook
wb = xw.Book()
sht = wb.sheets[0]

# Set up the dataframe in Excel
sht.range('B1:H1').api.merge()
sht["A1"].value ='Title:'
sht["B1"].value = title
sht["A3"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=True, expand='table').value = df
sht["A1"].expand("right").api.Font.Bold = True
sht["A3"].expand("right").api.Font.Bold = True
sht["A3"].expand("down").api.Font.Bold = True
 
# format borders with direct call
sht["A1"].expand("right").api.Borders(9).Color = xw.utils.rgb_to_int((255,0,0))
sht["A1"].expand("right").api.Borders(9).Weight = 4

# set color "red"
red = xw.utils.rgb_to_int((255,0,0))

# format borders in different ways with def function calls
format_borders(sht["A3"].expand("right"), 2, XlBordersIndex = 'xlBottomRightAll'
format_borders(sht["A3"].expand("down"), 2, XlBordersIndex = 'xlBottomRightAll')
format_borders(sht['A1:H1'], 4, XlBordersIndex = 'xlEdgeBottom', color = red)
format_borders(sht['C6:D7'], 4, 'xlCrossoutAll', red)
format_borders(sht["F8"], 3)
```